# using and disposing Attachment with MailMessage

Tags: c#, email, smtp, attachment

I have this code:

```
using (var msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
{
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromEmail);
    msg.To = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toEmail);        
    msg.Body = body;

    var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file);
    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    //using (var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file))
    //    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    using (var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp", 587))
    {
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }; 
}
```

The file attachment is *optional* in my case.
When I use `using` on `attachment`, the `smtp.Send()` throws:

> Inner Exception 1: ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed
>   file

My question is how to handle this correctly? 
Will the `MailMessage` dispose the internal attachment(s) also if I'm not explicitly using `Dispose` on the attachment(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the .net source code for [MailMessage](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs,270)

It will be disposed if there is attachment.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !disposed)
        {
            disposed = true;

            if(views != null){
                views.Dispose();
            }
            if(attachments != null){
                attachments.Dispose();
            }
            if(bodyView != null){
                bodyView.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```